# Which SingleLiveData can handle screen rotation and event emitted before observe

Tags: android, android-livedata

In my application, I need a `LiveData`, that emits once.

I found a good [solution](https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8), but it has a few issues:

- It does not handle the event, which has emitted before calling LiveData.observe.
- It does not handle the event, which has emitted while screen rotation (between fragment's `onDestroyView` and `onCreateView`).

Is there an implementation, that can handle all listed cases?

Answer (score 0):

I created my own solution, based on [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8). It handle all cases, described in question.

You can find it [on github](https://gist.github.com/but4er007/f46283c2945bae1fe778554f471194e7) with comments.

```
import androidx.annotation.MainThread
import androidx.collection.ArraySet
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer

class EventLiveData<T>() : MediatorLiveData<T>() {
    private val observers = ArraySet<ObserverWrapper<in T>>()
    private var needToHandleLastResult = false
    private val previouslyOwnersHashcodes = mutableSetOf<Int>()

    @MainThread
    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
        val ownerHashcode = owner.hashCode()
        val ownerAlreadyObserving = previouslyOwnersHashcodes.contains(ownerHashcode)
        val needToHandleResult = needToHandleLastResult && !ownerAlreadyObserving
        val wrapper = ObserverWrapper(observer, needToHandleResult)
        previouslyOwnersHashcodes.add(ownerHashcode)
        needToHandleLastResult = false
        observers.add(wrapper)
        super.observe(owner, wrapper)
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun removeObserver(observer: Observer<in T>) {
        if (observers.remove(observer)) {
            super.removeObserver(observer)
            return
        }
        val iterator = observers.iterator()
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            val wrapper = iterator.next()
            if (wrapper.observer == observer) {
                iterator.remove()
                super.removeObserver(wrapper)
                break
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        needToHandleLastResult = false
        super.onActive()
    }

    @MainThread
    override fun setValue(t: T?) {
        if (!hasActiveObservers()) {
            needToHandleLastResult = true
        }
        observers.forEach { it.newValue() }
        super.setValue(t)
    }

    private class ObserverWrapper<T>(
            val observer: Observer<T>,
            hasUnprocessedEvent: Boolean
    ) : Observer<T> {

        private var pending = hasUnprocessedEvent

        override fun onChanged(t: T?) {
            if (pending) {
                pending = false
                observer.onChanged(t)
            }
        }

        fun newValue() {
            pending = true
        }
    }
}
```